# Reuse/alter a DocuSign envelope, to update its document PDF, once the envelope is In Process

Tags: docusignapi

We need to be able to handle a scenario where the document PDF needs to be updated and resent, after the envelope is In Process.  Do we always need to create a new envelope or can we reuse the current envelope ID?

Our process goes roughly like this:

1. A PDF document is generated (not using a DocuSign template).
2. We create an envelope for the document PDF.
3. The first signer (our employee) signs the document (using an embedded signing page).
4. The other signers sign the document (also using an embedded signing page).

Firstly, we want to know if we're forced to incur another "sent" envelope (i.e. we're billed) every time we want to update a document PDF.  Secondly, we're looking for a clean way to implement updates, without the need to manage multiple envelopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will unfortunately have to make a new envelope if you want to make changes to the underlying document(s) of the envelope after it has been sent.  This is actually a fundamental part of the service and the reason is not to make you incur a new envelope - instead it's actually a security / legal requirement.

Imagine that we are in the old world and I need two people to sign a document on paper.  I have the first person sign, then before the second person signs I make a change to the document that says the first person owes me $1,000,000.  Then the second person signs, the document completes, and now you have a signature from both people but it contains content that the first person did not actually agree to (and they apparently owe you $1,000,000 now!).  That's the main reason why you can't change the underlying document once it's been sent.

Two possible workarounds I can think of:

```
1.  Add data fields or other Stick-eTabs to the envelope for the parts of the document that might change.
2.  Use the signer attachments tab to add additional documents.
```

For #1, let's say you send out a sales contract for $100,000, but after it's been sent a new price is determined.  If the $100,000 is in the document content itself then you can not edit it and you'd have to create a new envelope with the new document; however if it's through a Data Field then your recipients can simply edit the value as the document works towards completion.

For #2, there are special [Stick-eTabs](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features) you can add called **Signer Attachment Tabs** which allow recipients to attach whole documents and other files to the envelope.  You could utilize this to add your changes to the envelope.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ergin.  I was thinking more about reusing the same envelope ID and have everyone sign again from the beginning.  Your reply has answered my question anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a human involved in updating/replacing the document, or are you looking to fully automate the process with the API?  As Ergin stated, it's not possible to add/remove documents using the API once an Envelope has been Sent.  However, it IS possible for the Sender of the envelope to "Correct" (and re-send) the Envelope using the DocuSign web console -- including adding or removing documents for an Envelope that's already been Sent, but documents can be ONLY be removed/replaced IF none of the recipients have yet acted on the Envelope.  i.e., once at least one recipient has acted on the Envelope, it won't be possible for the Sender to remove/replace documents in the Envelope (although they can Add new documents, as long as the Envelope is still in-process).

You can use the API to launch the "Correct Envelope" view as follows:

POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{acctId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/correct

The response to this operation will return a URL that you can use to launch the "Correct Envelope" view.

Finally, one important caveat about using the "Correct Envelope" feature to enable the Sender to modify documents in an envelope:  once the person is logged into the DocuSign web console where they'll correct the envelope, they'll have full access to that user account in the DocuSign web console -- i.e, they'll be able to access all Envelopes in that user account (Sent Items, Inbox, Deleted Items, etc.), send new Envelopes, access user settings via "Preferences", etc. So, be careful using the Correct view if you're concerned at all with providing the person with full access to that user account within the DocuSign web console.

Note: In order for the Sender to be able to add/remove Documents in the "Correct Envelope" view, the "Advanced Correct" feature must be enabled for the DocuSign account (in Preferences >> Features).

Comment: Thanks Kim.  It needs to be fully automated.

Comment: Okay, in that case -- to add/remove documents for an in-process Envelope in a fully automated fashion, you'd need a couple of API calls: 1) Void original envelope, 2) create/send new envelope.